# Formatting date format of Gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, gridview, formatting

I am confused on formatting date format in a gridview cell from (dd/MM/yyyy H:ss:mm) to (yyyy-MM-dd).

However, I haven't created any column in .aspx-page, but using dynamic binding from SQL to bind result to Gridview datasource. So, adding code which is similar bellowing is not working fine.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So, is there any way to changing formatting of the date value?

Comment: In query, its already a DATE type value. Once Gridview.databind(), date will be shown as 'dd/MM/yyyy H:ss:mm'.

Comment: @Edmund what is the field's type in the database? If it's *any* of the date-related types you don't need to convert. Dates have **NO** format, they are binary types. The query will return them as `DateTime` so a simple `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` would be enough.

Comment: @Edmund If it's text, you have a serious bug - you should use the *correct* type to store dates. No matter how certain you are that the strings will always look like `dd/MM/yyyy` someone will always enter text in a different format. It might even be you. Once that happens you won't be able to find the incorrect values - what does `04/05/2018` mean?

Comment: @KarthikeyanNagaraj string formatting in SQL is a *very* bad idea. The double conversion is even worse. There's no need to convert to text if the field is a `date` or `datetime`, the date values will be retrieved as DateTime values ready for display and formatting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it in RowDataBound event

```
protected void gvrequests_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
          string strTemp= e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

        e.Row.Cells[3].Text=Convert.ToDateTime(strTemp).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt")
        }
   }
```

Comment: nonono, i dont even have code like '<itemTemplate> xxxxxx </ItemTemplate>' in my aspx page. All item / columns are generated in dynamic way though MSSQL. So coding like <ItemTemplate> is useless.

Comment: in SQL, value is already a DATE type. I think it should be a GridView formatting problem.

Comment: @Edmund if it's a date type, remove Convert.ToDateTime. The value you read is *already* a DateTime. `Eval("StartDate").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` is enough

Answer (score 1):

Replace your binding code with :

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("StartDate", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Don't change your query, in fact make sure `StartDate` is returned as a `date` or `datetime`. If you convert the date field to text with `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` remove the conversion.

**Explanation**

If the database field is a date-related type, eg `date`, `datetime` etc it has no format. It's a binary value. When you read it, unless you *explicitly* convert it to a string (bad idea) it is retrieved as a DateTime value, which also doesn't have any format. Formats apply only when you convert the binary values to strings.

[DataBinder.Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload that accepts a format string, similar to `String.Format` and returns a string.

The docs show how to use this overload to generate URL links :

```
<a href='<%# Eval("ProductID", "details.asp?id={0}") %>'>See Details</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvote. Good thing there's a bot that clears serial downvotes